# ActionMode smaller than the Toolbar in landscape

Tags: android, android-toolbar, landscape-portrait, android-actionmode

I want be able to resize the actionMode or at least have an actionMode with same size of the toolbar.

I have a toolbar with fixed size in portrait and landscape. I'm using 56dp (mobile portrait toolbar value) as value for both.

My toolbar is ok. The issue is that during the orientation change my actionMode get the default value from android ?attr/actionBarSize so in landscape I end up with an actionMode smaller than the toolbar.

Normal ActionMode code

```
if (actionMode == null) {
    actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
}
```

I tried in onConfigurationChanged to change the size of the actionMode but with no luck. This is an example to change the size of the toolbar. Apparently there's no way to do the same for the actionMode. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toolbar toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getToolbar(); //my custom method to get the toolbar
            if (toolbar != null) {
                int toolbarHeight = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
                toolbar.setMinimumHeight(toolbarHeight);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = toolbarHeight;
                toolbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Apparently it doesn't matter if you set layout_height of the toolbar in your layout and the size of the actionMode in the style, see below.

a layout with a toolbar with fixed height

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/actionMode</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/WindowActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/toolbar_height</item> // This fix the issue
    </style>
<style name="WindowActionMode">
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/toolbar_height</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/toolbar_height</item>
</style>
```

You have to also set the actionBarSize in the style.

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/toolbar_height</item>
```

I guess the actionMode use the ?attr/actionBarSize so if you want to use a fixed toolbar set also the actionBarSize in your theme.